# How to get rid of zeros in a calculation so an error does not occur Python

Tags: python, eval, calculator, calculation

Hi I am working on a calculator program and am trying to solve an issue where when a zero is in front of the calculation.

For example, `03+03` an error occurs as I am using `eval`. the calculation must be kept in string form as `eval` uses the string form and gives me the sum. I need to find a way to get rid of the zeros before the calculation happens through `eval`.

Comment: Please show your code, instead of just describing it. See [mcve]. (also example input/output if necessary)

Comment: Eval is evil. (

Answer (score 2):

Here is a completely working code. I assume you want to remove leftmost trailing zero of a number.

```
import re

calculation = '03030+010340'
res = re.sub('^0*|(?<=[-\+\*/])0*', '', calculation) 
print(res)

# 3030+10340
```

**How?**

`re.sub` substitutes a pattern with whatever we want.

Inside `re.sub`:

1. First parameter is the pattern to be substituted.
   `^0*` matches starting `0` zero or more times.
   `(?<=[-\+\*/])0*` matches `0`s that follow `-`, `+`, `*`, `/` operators.
2. Second parameter is to specify what to replace with.
3. Third parameter is the input string.

Also, I suggest not to use `eval`. Read about dangers of `eval` [here](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html). Use `ast.literal_eval` to get result of operation like so:

```
ast.literal_eval(res)  # Don't forget to import ast
```

Comment: I've included explanation with answer. Hope this helps.